How to build Azure AI endpoint and deployments of models using pipelines
Using Azure Portal and AI Studio, I created the deployment of two models selected on AI Studio, an endpoint and a workspace.  I don't really know what I'm doing and try to learn by doing.  Now I need to create all these by scripts in pipelines with YAML and BICEP so I can teardown at night and rebuild in the morning.  I would want an endpoint that can serve two or more models.
I saw script samples with inference and deployment file but couldn't find how to fill those files based on the objects I have in the portal.
I saw another sample with a YAML with :
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.x'
    addToPath: true
- script: |
    pip install azureml-core azureml-sdk
- script: |
    az ml online-endpoint create -n 'my-endpoint' -f ./create_or_update_endpoint.yml -g 'resources_group_name' -w 'workspace_name'
    az ml online-endpoint update -n 'my-endpoint' --traffic 'deployment_name=100' -g 'resources_group_name' -w 'workspace_name'

But using this script I got:
ext/_ruamel_yaml.c:181:12: fatal error: longintrepr.h: No such file or directory
        181 |   #include "longintrepr.h"
            |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for ruamel.yaml

How can I build my endpoint and deployments of two models using pipelines ?

To narrow down the cause of the issue, can you run the commands on local machine before integrating in pipelines? Are you running this pipeline on a MS-hosted Linux agent or your self-hosted agent? If on MS-hosted agent, how the az ml online-endpoint create and az ml online-endpoint update commands could authenticate access to your ML workspace? From the current script, we don't know how the file longintrepr.h was used or what your repo file structure was like, which could have incurred the error: longintrepr.h: No such file or directory.

thank you for your answer, I'm behind a firewall, I'm unable to test local first but I reduced my pipeline running on MS-hosted: pool:
vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
stages:

stage: DeployModels
jobs:

job: DeployToEndpoint
steps:


checkout: self


task: UsePythonVersion@0
inputs:
versionSpec: '3.x'
addToPath: true


script: |
pip install azureml-core azureml-sdk






I still got the error, just trying to install: ext/_ruamel_yaml.c:181:12: fatal error: longintrepr.h: No such file or directory ... "longintrepr.h", wrong image ?

I am afraid I am not so familiar with AzureML as Azure DevOps. Since you are behind a firewall, how could the az ml online-endpoint create and az ml online-endpoint update authenticate access to your workspace from MS-hosted agent via public network? If you were using a self-hosted agent, you should be able to connect to the machine to run those commands as well for a test as well.

Interesting comment as I'm not familiar with AI, ML...  I started last year building CI/CD for resources on Azure using pipelines.  For authentication, we create  a Service Principal in Azure that has owner rights on the resources group and we define it as service connection in Azure DevOps so it is this account that runs the pipelines and scripts.  I used  a self-hosted agent in the past, I could go back there but the goal of this project is to use Azure.  It is strange that only running pip install azureml-core azureml-sdk on this 'ubuntu-latest image fails.   Should I try other VM?

It is only a fact that I am not so familiar with AzureML as Azure DevOps. I also found it interesting that you mentioned that you created a Service Connection authenticating against your Service Principal in Azure, while you simply used a script task which didn't refence any service connection.

You might need to use AzureCLI task instead to reference the service connection and run those az ml commands; howerver, I still suspected it was an authentication issue based on the error message. This was also why I suggested from the troubleshooting perspective of Azure DevOps that you try and run those commands successfully before integrating in pipelines to isolate the root cause of the failure. Anyway, please feel welcome to engage the insights from the community experts on Azure ML Azure AI.

Digging deeper, I understood that to call az ml online-endpoint create from an Azure Pipeline, I should use an AzureCli task and install the extensions I needed.
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: $(azureServiceConnection)
      scriptType: 'bash'
      scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
      inlineScript: |
        az extension add -n ml -y
        az ml workspace list --resource-group $(resourceGroupName)

This worked.  I had other issues but that's another story.
Thanks.
